# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to-4} \frac{\large \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{x}}{4 + x}$

Tags: limits, roots, radicals, limits-without-lhopital, rationalising-denominator

**Background :** I'm currently studying for my calc mid-term which is coming up, and stumbled upon a couple of questions which I don't understand on how to solve.

**Question :** Evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to-4} \frac{\large \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{x}}{4 + x}$$

**My Thought Process :** I realize that just "plugging in" won't work, so I need to multiply by the conjugate $\large \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{x}$, however that's where my problem comes in. I don't remember, how to do this.

Also, I have a similar problem but with a root.

$$\lim_{x\to 7} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-3}{x-7}$$

Once again, plugging in won't work, so I need to multiply by it's conjugate $\sqrt{x+2} + 3$, however I don't know what the result would be. If anyone could help explain this to me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In the first one, no conjugate, just simplify the fraction. In the second, be sure to multiply top and bottom by the same thing, and don't forget $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, and don't forget $(\sqrt Q)^2=Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of observations, which should enable you to get your answer.

For the first one,
$$\dfrac{\dfrac14 + \dfrac1x}{4+x} = \dfrac{\dfrac{x+4}{4x}}{4+x} = \dfrac1{4x} \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{for }x \neq -4$$

For the second one,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}-3}{x-7} & = \dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}-3}{x-7} \times \dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}+3}{\sqrt{x+2}+3} = \dfrac{(\sqrt{x+2})^2 - 3^2}{(x-7)(\sqrt{x+2} + 3)} = \dfrac{x+2-9}{(x-7)(\sqrt{x+2}+3)}\\
& = \dfrac{x-7}{(x-7)(\sqrt{x+2} + 3)} = \dfrac1{\sqrt{x+2}+3} \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{for }x \neq 7
\end{align}

Comment: Now we'll never know whether OP could have worked any of that out.

Comment: For the second part, couldn't you keep going further and end up with (1 / (sqrt(x+2) +3))?